# Passing Information From Twilio Widgets to Twilio Functions

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-studio

I have a flow setup in Twilio studio. The flow asks for an extension. That information is then passed through a conditional block.
If the person presses 1, it goes somewhere specifc, the same if 2 is pressed, and all the rest are transitioned to a script. How do I get the pressed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is add parameters in the function, and pass the parameters through the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get the pressed button value, you can use the `Gather Input on Call` widget ([more info on that here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call)). Your flow may look something like this then: [image]

Let me know if this helps at all! :D

Comment: I must not have explained, I do gather the information, but I'm trying to pass it into a function

Answer (score 0):

The first response is correct with the addition of adding the parameters to the Twilio Studio Run Function widget using the syntax in the 2nd response, widgets.gather_1.Digits (assuming your Widget is named gather_1) as the value for your key.

In the Twilio function, you can pull in this value using the event object and the key you used for the widgets.gather_1.Digits value. You can print it out in your Twilio function using

```
console.log(event.myKeyName);
```